# How to show hidden elements in Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have hidden my div's with hidden="true" which is working but
I want to show it after a button click.

I work with Node.js and this part must be coded in Javascript.

html:

```
div class="sideDiv" hidden="true">
```

javascript:

I tried it with show() but it doesn't work.

```
socket.on('loginInServer',function(data){
        $('.sideDiv').show();
    });
```

Comment: You say after a button click but where is your click event listener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said above, you should get rid of the hidden attribute and hide the element using the css instead.

```
.sideDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

Then the jquery's show() method will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.sideDiv').attr('hidden', false);
```

But you probably want to hide it in the first place not using the hidden attribute, which honestly I have not seen anyone use (other than for hidden form fields).

The simplest way is to have this in your css:

```
.sideDiv{display: none;}
```

Or if you're lazy you can embed this on the element itself in html:

```
<div class="sideDiv" style="display: none"></div>
```

Then when your page loads, it will be hidden and what you're doing with .show() will work since that jQuery function operates on the "display" style of a dom element.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the attribute using [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method.

```
ocket.on('loginInServer',function(data){
    $('.sideDiv').removeAttr('hidden');
});
```

---

Or update the attribute to false using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
ocket.on('loginInServer',function(data){
    $('.sideDiv').attr('hidden', false);
});
```

---

Or set the property false using [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop) method.

```
ocket.on('loginInServer',function(data){
    $('.sideDiv').prop('hidden', false);
});
```

---

**FYI :** For hiding element set CSS [`display:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) which would be the much better way and later you can show using [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) method.

Answer (score 2):

The style `"display:none"` and attribute `hidden="true"` renders differently.

[`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

> The hidden global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can't be used until the login process has been completed. Browsers won't render elements with the hidden attribute set.

jQuery's `show` changes the `style` of an element and does not modify the attribute `hidden`

[show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

> ... This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ) ...

You will want to use jQuery's `attr` or `prop` to modify the attribute `hidden`

```
$('.sideDiv').attr('hidden', false);

$('.sideDiv').prop('hidden', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to previous answers, you can do it also in plain JS:

```
document.querySelector(".sideDiv").setAttribute("hidden", "false");
```